# How to define the way instance model should be rendered in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-6, warden, hotwire-rails

I'm using Hotwire and devise User on a Rails 6.0.3.6 app.

I add this broadcast for Users

```
class User    
  after_create_commit { broadcast_append_to 'users' }
end
```

Then when a User is created it goes through his partial (*users/user*) where I am trying to use `current_user` Devise helper.

But Rails throw this error:

```
Devise::MissingWarden in Players::Registrations#update
Devise could not find the `Warden::Proxy` instance on your request environment.
Make sure that your application is loading Devise and Warden as expected and that the `Warden::Manager` middleware is present in your middleware stack.
```

Maybe the solution would be to be able to tell Rails the following:

If from a model, you are trying to render his default partial (.to_partial_path) you need to pass it some locals variables,like `user: self`.

How could I say that to Rails ?

Thanks for you help

Comment: Could it have something to do with the initializer _application_controller_renderer.br_ ?

Answer (score 3):

DHH said:

> Partials used for turbo streaming have to be free of global
> references, as they’re rendered by the ApplicationRenderer, not within
> the context of a specific request.

https://discuss.hotwire.dev/t/authentication-and-devise-with-broadcasts/1752/4