# How to access current_user helper with Hotwire & Turbo.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo

I’m following [this tutorial](https://gorails.com/episodes/realtime-nested-comments-part-3?autoplay=1) to implement a feature where user can submit Trivia/Interesting Facts.

I want to restrict (edit/delete) functionality to the admin or author of each item.

I’ve created a helper class in .application_controller

```
def author_of?(resource)
user_signed_in? && current_user.id == resource.user_id
end
```

But when I'm using this in Turbo-frame with Hotwire I’m getting this error

**| ActionView::Template::Error (Devise could not find the `Warden::Proxy` instance on your request environment.**

Here's my code for reference

**index.html**

```
<%= turbo_stream_from @stadium, :trivia %>
<%= tag.div id: "#{dom_id(@stadium)}_trivia" do %>
    <%= render partial: "trivia/trivium", collection: @stadium.trivia %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

**_trivium.html.erb**

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag trivium do %>

<%= trivium.body %>

<% if author_of?(trivium) || admin? %>
<%= button_to "Delete", trivium_path(trivium), class: "btn btn-small btn-danger btn-link mr-2", method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

How can I access the current_user helper in the comment partial to check if the current_user is the author or admin (and should be allow to delete/edit)?

Answer (score 2):

The reason this errors is, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67074124/how-to-define-the-way-instance-model-should-be-rendered-in-rails-6), partials with Turbo frames are rendered without any of your global helpers available.

That SO question points to a Hotwire forum [here](https://discuss.hotwire.dev/t/authentication-and-devise-with-broadcasts/1752/10) where they discuss possible solutions. The best one in my view is described [here](https://blog.cloud66.com/making-hotwire-and-devise-play-nicely-with-viewcomponents/).

The gist is:

- Pass in current_user as an argument to your partial, rather than accessing it from within your partial
- Do your permission check within the partial, rather than the helper

```
<%= render partial: "trivia/trivium", collection: @stadium.trivia, user: current_user %>
```

You might consider turning your author_of method into a model method as well, and then you'll have the option to use it within your partial.